# Creating a html site with javascript and save it to the server

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I am working on a little site for users to fill out some kind of "survey" and when they are finished it'll create a html site based on the information, the point is how can I save the newly created html site as a .html document on the server?

Comment: You'll need to use a server-side environment like PHP.

Comment: You will need to use PHP or another server-side language to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: You cannot save anything to a server with plain JavaScript. JavaScript is a **client side language** - maximum you can do is send the data to the server via JavaScript and then process it there with a **server side language** like PHP, Ruby, Java or also JavaScript in combination with Node.js.

If you are a beginner with web development I would recommend you doing the saving with PHP - it is quite simple and there are a lot of tutorials out there in the internet.

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: you are welcome. Please close the thread when you are done ;)